# Sprite mask collision doesnt work (rect collision works)

Tags: python, pygame

The collision works when I use:

```
pygame.sprite.collide_rect
```

but it doesnt work when I use:

```
pygame.sprite.collide_mask
```

Here are my 2 classes:

```
class Ball():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = balltexture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=225
        self.rect.y=400
        self.radius = 100
        self.velx=0
        self.vely=0
        self.action=False
        self.switchx=0
        self.switchy=0        
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(balltexture)
    def draw(self):
        win.blit(balltexture, self.rect)


class rock():
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.rect = rocktexture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = screensize.current_w
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = 120
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(rocktexture)


    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(rocktexture, self.rect)
```

and here is the collision check

```
for i in rocks:
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(i, Player):
        print(1)
        if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(i, Player):
            print(2)
```

So when they collide it prints 1 all the time.

BTW I'm moving rect coordinates (e.g. Player.rect.x) to move the Player/rocks and I also tried the mask overlap method but it didn't work either

```
offset = (Player.rect.x-i.rect.x, Player.rect.y-i.rect.y)
if i.mask.overlap(Player.mask, offset):
    print(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my images had no transparency, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what's going on, but here's some things to try:

You can set the mask to all 1s with self.mask.fill(). At this point, the mask collision should be identical to the rect-based collision.

You can call print(self.mask.count()), which will show the number of set pixels. Make sure it's not 0 or something.

You can call i.mask.overlap(Player.mask (0, 0)), and confirm that those overlap when they have the same upper-left corner.

This is either going to be an issue with the mask creation, or the offsets are wrong in some way; this should narrow down the issue.

Comment: the problem was that one of the images had no transparency